# Lookup by widget id in Widget template

Tags: gtk3

There's a way of lookup by widget's id in widget template ?

by "widget template" I mean `gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource`

I've tried define following function in window class:

```
GtkWidget *
lookup_widget (CustomAppWindow *win,
               const char      *name)
{
    return GTK_WIDGET (gtk_widget_get_template_child (GTK_WIDGET (win),
                                                      GTK_TYPE_WIDGET,
                                                      name));
}
```

but the `gtk_widget_get_template_child` always returns null.

Comment: if `gtk_widget_get_template_child()` is returning `NULL`, are you sure you're using the right name? that's the most common case.

Comment: also, ensure you're calling `gtk_widget_init_template()` from your instance initialization function.

Comment: @ebassi yes, it's correct name, and I'm calling gtk_widget_init_template in _init(); I've accept your answer, since it fits my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

calling `gtk_widget_get_template_child()` should never return NULL — but you should rarely have to call that function in the first place.

the correct way to access objects defined with GTK widget templates is to add a member to your instance data structure with the same name as in the XML definition, and then call `gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child()`.

for instance, given the following XML description:

```xml
<interface>
  <template class="FooWidget" parent="GtkBox">
    <property name="orientation">GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL</property>
    <property name="spacing">4</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="hello_button">
        <property name="label">Hello World</property>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="hello_button_clicked" object="FooWidget" swapped="yes"/>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="goodbye_button">
        <property name="label">Goodbye World</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </template>
</interface>
```

when creating your widget instance you typically will add two `GtkWidget` members in the instance data structure, such as:

```cpp
typedef struct _FooWidget {
    GtkBox parent_instance;

    GtkWidget *hello_button;
    GtkWidget *goodbye_button;
} FooWidget;
```

from your class initialization function, you will have to call the `gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child()` function after setting the template:

```cpp
static void
foo_widget_class_init (FooWidgetClass *klass)
{
  // ...
  gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource (GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (klass),
                                               "/com/example/foo/widget.ui");
  gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child (GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (klass),
                                        FooWidget, hello_button);
  gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child (GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (klass),
                                        FooWidget, goodbye_button);
}
```

the template machinery inside GTK+ will ensure that the fields are set on instance initialization, and unset on instance finalization. this means that you can access those fields from your instance init right after you called `gtk_widget_init_template()`:

```cpp
static void
foo_widget_init (FooWidget *self)
{
  gtk_widget_init_template (GTK_WIDGET (self));

  // now you can access self->hello_button and self->goodbye_button
}
```

if you are not writing an application, or you want to hide the components of your composite widget from your instance structure, you can use a private structure and call `gtk_widget_class_bind_template_private_child()` instead.

remember you can also bind functions defined in your local scope to signal handlers defined in the XML, using `gtk_widget_class_bind_template_callback()`.